# Excel VBA custom functions recalculate not working

Tags: excel, vba, custom-functions-excel

I have some custom functions in VBA, which I want to recalculate with standard excel buttons **"Calculate Now"** and **"Calculate sheet"**. The whole workbook has set **"calculate options"** to **"manual"**.

When I press "Calculate sheet" button, everything works fine. I can recalculate the sheets one by one as many times as I want.

**The problem arises if I press "Calculate Now" button.** The whole workbook is recalculated, **but further recalculation is no longer possible**. Neither with button "Calculate Now", nor "Calculate Sheet".

I was hoping that it was possible to capture the **"Calculate Now"** event, catch it and call it to the "Calculate Sheet" event of the individual sheets. Or after function `Worksheet_Calculate()` set some flags for cells to register them to next recalculation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   ' Register all cells in sheet to next recalculation
End Sub
```

Is it possible to get rid of this problem? **I want to use standard excel buttons for recalculations. but I need them to work every time I press them.**

Comment: does it trigger Worksheet_Calculate() the second time you click Calculate Now?

Comment: No. Only first time. It seems, that second "recalculate now" or "recalculate sheet" after "recalculate now" is not working for any cell. I need to calculate the cell manually and then the recalculate buttons works again, but only on the one current cell.

Comment: It seems, that "Calculate now" button mark the cells somehow, that the cells should not be calculated again. This mark can be reset by manual cell calculation and then e.g. expand the cells. These cells could be calculate again. But the "Calculate now" button triggers the "error" again. :)

Comment: what does the 'Calculate now' button do? Application.calculate?

Comment: Would making your UDFs volatile not solve the problem you're trying to workaround?

Comment: @CLR Yes!!! The volatile solved it. :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviors of "Calculate Now" and "Calculate sheet" are by design. Because after "Calculate Now", all will be calculated. Without any change, nothing is needed to calculated again. But "Calculate sheet" only calculate the worksheet based on maybe some stale data. So it will be calculated again next time.

Suggest you using "Application.AfterCalculate" event. It will be fired after every "Calculate Now".

Hope all that is helpful.

Comment: I have used volatile UDF, it solved my problem but thanks.